# Not working - Hover on variable to see value in debug prespective in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, variables, hover

I am using classic Eclipse 3.6.1.
I have a Java project which is throwing an exception because of a stack overflow.
Unlike other editors, when I hover my mouse pointer on a variable it does not show me the value of that variable.
Here are the settings in

```
Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Hovers
Combined Hover - Shift
Variable Values - Ctrl
Source - Shift+Ctrl
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. I have seen threads by others about this same problem but could not find a solution. Is this a bug that hasn't been fixed yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Go to Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Hovers.

```
Is "Combined Hover" selected? Uncheck it; apply; close the window; restart debugging session; go back; check it again; apply.
If the above doesn't help, you can check "Variable Values" option and specify a modifier key for it. Not as convenient as "combined", but should work.
```

The problem gets "fixed" by renaming the package.

For whatever reason, this refactoring triggers something in Eclipse, and immediately I was able to view variable values during debugging. Also, when I go back into Preferences under Hovers, I can now see the "Variable Values" option.

Comment: I added a modifier, and I am able to use the modifier to see the variable values. But, its a pain. The normal hover keeps going to javadoc or method signature.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Preferences under Hovers were checked and enabled. Even after that it was not showing values when I move the mouse on the variable. Problem has been fixed by simply closing and reopening the Eclipse (I was using Eclipse with Python).