# Visual Studio 2015 update 3 crashing after "Getting DataTip text..."

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

When debugging a C# application in Visual Studio 2015, I am *very often* getting this message when hovering the mouse over a variable:

[image]

After this it freezes and restart, making it impossible to debug.

Anyone have any clue?

Comment: Take a look: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8653d0d1-c7ed-4194-8fdc-f183d4ff4ec2/problems-with-debugging-in-vs-2015-when-execution-is-in-a-thread?forum=vsdebug

Comment: Indeed, I found this article when I was looking for a solution.
I also found these:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f3e0c708-0cb4-4e15-9f80-8e713870ebcd/debugging-cant-hover-over-variables-to-see-their-values?forum=visualstudiogeneral
and
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/
But nothing is solving this for good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that checking this option: 
**Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General: "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"**.

avoids Visual Studio 2015 from crashing but disables **Edit and Continue**... which is no good.

So, I am still looking for a better answer.

Sources:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8653d0d1-c7ed-4194-8fdc-f183d4ff4ec2/problems-with-debugging-in-vs-2015-when-execution-is-in-a-thread?forum=vsdebug
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f3e0c708-0cb4-4e15-9f80-8e713870ebcd/debugging-cant-hover-over-variables-to-see-their-values?forum=visualstudiogeneral
- [Datatips (mouse hover over variables in debug mode) not working in Visual Studio 2012 / Win 7 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108801/datatips-mouse-hover-over-variables-in-debug-mode-not-working-in-visual-studio)
- [Visual Studio 2015 Debugging: Can't expand local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730100/visual-studio-2015-debugging-cant-expand-local-variables)
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/

Quoting the last one:

> In Visual Studio 2012, we introduced a new managed debug engine that provides us the ability to more rapidly add new features compared to the older implementation. This can be seen by the number of features introduced in Visual Studio 2013 after only a single year including Managed Return Values, .NET 64-bit Edit and Continue, Async Callstacks Enhancements, and Improved Tasks Window to name a few. Unfortunately, there are still a couple scenarios that are not supported yet with the new debug engine, so in these cases you will have to switch back to the legacy engine.

...so it seems that this is not new.

Answer (score 7):

Like that thread shared by duDE, please disable the option "Enable property Evaluation and other implicit function calls" under Tools->Options->Debugging->General.

Comment: Resolved in Visual Studio "15" Preview 5: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/10/05/announcing-visual-studio-15-preview-5/

Comment: this worked for me. You need to close Visual Studio after the change though to take effect. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed in Visual Studio "15" Preview 5 (available [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/10/05/announcing-visual-studio-15-preview-5/). For Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 there are, unfortunately, no known workarounds other than those already mentioned.