# Only in unit test projects

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

Is this a new feature of VS 2017 that every time I am trying to debug a unit test, and point the cursor at a variable to inspect, VS freezes at first, then throw up this:

[image]

And if I hit F10 after this window finally goes away in 10-20 seconds, VS throws up this:

[image]

Is this a new normal and expected behavior, or I am missing any settings?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the latest information in your side? Is it related to the debugging option in your side?

Answer (score 0):

1)            Please try to disable the option "**Enable property Evaluation and other implicit function calls**" under Tools->Options->Debugging->General.
2)            **Delete all of the breakpoints**, reset the one that you want and debug again.
3)            Another workaround could be to enable the option: "**Use Managed Compatibility Mode**" under Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, but it will disable Edit and Continue. Reference: [Visual Studio 2015 update 3 crashing after "Getting DataTip text..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663779/visual-studio-2015-update-3-crashing-after-getting-datatip-text)
4)            Btw, the latest update of VS 2017 is **15.5.3**, you may also try to update to it.

And of course, you could post the unit test code sample if it’s possible, since I could not reproduce this issue with unit test project in VS2017.

Comment: And by the way, this is on 15.5.3

Comment: Use Managed Compatibility Mode is greyed out. Your other suggestions made no difference.

Comment: @ajeh Same issue was reported before: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/11008/debugger-popping-up-getting-datatip-text.html however VS team has not fixed it yet, maybe because it could not be reproduced mostly, but VS team also suggest to report it via Help-> Send feedback in VS if it happens in the latest version of Visual Studio.

Comment: You can suggest things, it's Okay, but I will continue doing what I deem most convenient for me, as I do not get paid for improving Microsoft products. If you want me to do something, you will have to pay me. Until then, I'll post here, or elsewhere, where it is convenient for me, or not post at all. Having me improve your products for free is too nice for a corporation worth 100 billion $$. I am certainly not opening another online account just to help you for free.