# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't show tooltip on debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, tooltip, visual-studio-2017

I recently downloaded visual studio 2017 because developing xamarin apps, has many utilities in more, that make me comfortable.

That said, I wonder if any of you have already downloaded and if the tooltip problem in debugging, I do not see anything.
And so it is impossible to work. But panel "Locals" work.
I searched online but it is still too early to find help.
If anyone has had the same problem and solved tell me.
Thank you.

[image]

i have tryed to reinstall, but don't work.

Comment: It resembles [this bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14222).  Surely no match, do click the New button to report it.

Comment: tooltip is gone when using System.ValueTuple.  I'm on a VSTO project.

Comment: with the last update of visual studio 2017 now works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common problem, but there are several different solutions and I think I know what your problem is.  Using Xamarin? Shared project? Can see some local variables but nothing inside of an async method?

1. Everyone will tell you to check that your solution configuration is set to DEBUG and not RELEASE. This is the basic answer, "Set to DEBUG, clean, rebuild..", and to go a bit deeper, you can select Configuration Manager from the dropdown to check that not only is the project you are debugging set to DEBUG, but so are all of the (if any) projects that are dependencies.
   [image]
2. But I'm thinking your project properties is the issue. If you are doing Xamarin and have a shared project or portable project (probably the one that has the async method that wont allow you do debug correctly!) In the portable project properties, under Build -> Advanced, change Debugging information to full and you should be good to go!
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Changing the Debugging information in Advanced Build Settings worked for me. It was already on "Full" so I changed it to something else before going back to "Full", and now tooltips are showing!

Answer (score 1):

check if your build configuration for projects is set to 'Debug'. Also look at this one -> [debug watch stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108801/datatips-mouse-hover-over-variables-in-debug-mode-not-working-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
workaround:

1) Place current debugger statement (the yellow arrow) one line back.
2) Execute current statement again.

This worked for me.
[image]