# Can I see datatips in Visual Studio (vb.net) when I hover over variables in a With block?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Very often in the code I'm working with, there are blocks of code like this:

```
Dim myDataTable As DataTable
Dim myValue As String
...
With myDataTable.Rows(0)
    .Item("foo") = myValue
End With
myDataTable.Rows(0).Item("foo") += 1
```

Inside the With statement while debugging, I can hover over myValue and see the contents of that variable. I can also hover over the word Item in myDataTable.Rows(0).Item("foo") and see the contents of that element of the object.

However, I can't hover over the .Item("foo") in the With statement and see the contents of the variable there. I can't change the structure of the code to remove the with statements, because it would change thousands of lines of code and significantly lose readability.

I've tried most of the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108801/datatips-mouse-hover-over-variables-in-debug-mode-not-working-in-visual-studio), but they don't have any impact on the particular sub-case I'm having issues with here.

Is there any setting or any other way to get Visual Studio to display those datatips?

Comment: If you select that bit of code with your mouse and then hover over it, I think that you should see what you want.

Comment: I tried selecting "With myDataTable.Rows(0)" and '.Item("foo")', and neither allowed me to see the value in .Item("foo"). It did change the behavior when I hovered over myDataTable.Rows(0) to show me the types instead of the values, but that's not what I'm looking for.